# Disallowed Key Characters in jquery with Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, safari

I have problem with Safari browser when I want to load picture with jQuery in the Codeigniter framework. The loader is blocked. When I use Firebug, I find the error :

```
[uploader] responseText = Disallowed Key Characters
```

Comment: i have this probleme just in safari  borwser , it works fine in chrome and firefox

Comment: post the jquery script you're using to load the picture.

Answer (score 0):

please edit your config file to allow the custom characters

eg:$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_-@&';